# How do I retrieve an image from the cursor in android? getImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to build a music player. To add the song data in the RecyclerView I created an ArrayList (thisList) which contains the song data including the album art but I can't figure out how to add the image to the list :(

```
 if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);

        int albumArtColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);

        //ImageView thisAlbumArt = musicCursor. ????

        theList.add(newSong(thisId,thisTitle,
                      thisArtist,thisAlbum,thisAlbumArt));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor artCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART},
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+" =?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(albumId)},
    null);
String albumArt;
if(artCursor.moveToNext()) {
    albumArt = "file://"+artCursor.getString(0);
} else {
    albumArt = null;
}
artCursor.close();

if(albumArt != null) {
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(albumArt));
}
```